# Adjust spacing between list of tables and the title of each table

Tags: spacing

I am working on my thesis formatting (in report documentclass). I used "tocloft" package to adjust the fontsize of the toc, lot and lof. I was wondering how to adjust the spacing between list of tables and the title of each table.
[image]
and similarly for lof and toc.
[image]
Thanks!

----------update----------------

Thank you for the advice. Here are the codes I'm using.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,
]{geometry}


\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} %for example
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{cleveref} %for section symbol

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{commath}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}%[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exa}{Example}[section]

\usepackage{float} %!!!

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=TABLE}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\normalsize}{%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tocloft}  %customize title of fig & tab 
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{7em}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }

\renewcommand{\cfttabnumwidth}{7em}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{TABLE }

\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftlottitlefont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\large\bfseries}
\newcommand\at[2]{\left.#1\right|_{#2}} %Derivative at a point
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\doublespacing
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\setcounter{page}{4}
\tableofcontents{}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagebreak

\listoftables
\thispagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\pagebreak

\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\pagebreak


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{History of polynomial root-finding}

...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting images it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what you are doing and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. It is really difficult to help you without seeing some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `tocloft` manual:

> [image: Blockquote]

To change the spacing below the table of contents heading, you can therefore use `\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{<lenght of your choice>}`. The default length (according to `tocloft.sty` is `40pt`.

Here is a small MWE demonstrating the usage of the before mentioned command:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{10pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{a Chapter Title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's working! Thank you!